# Process variable between functions

Tags: function, variables, python-3.x, tkinter

When I try to get value of variable I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Here is code:

```
class whatever(x):

    def get_inpt(self):
        print (self.createWidgets().name.get())

    def createWidgets(self):
        name = Entry(self).grid()
```

I want to have `createWidgets` function because of tidiness and also keep `get_inpt` out of it.

Q: How to process `name` value between functions?

Working on `Python-3.4.2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, your `createWidgets` method isn't returning anything, so the result of `self.createWidgets()` is `None`. `None` objects don't have a `name` attribute, so you're getting an error.

Assign the Entry to an attribute of `self`, such as `self.name`. Also, you should never assign and `grid` on the same line - then the variable won't contain the widget, it will contain the return value of `grid`, which is `None`.

```
class whatever(x):
    def __init__(self):
        self.createWidgets()
    def get_inpt(self):
        print (self.name.get())
    def createWidgets(self):
        self.name = Entry(self)
        self.name.grid()
```